# Can I apply 100% SEO to angularjs or generating pages at server side is more effective?

Tags: angularjs, seo

I'm creating a shopping and advertising web site , I'm going to create a public `api` at the server side and let other devices connect to that.

I'm going to use `angularjs` as the client side for web browsers,but the `SEO` is very important to me .

I know that `SEO` is achievable in angular using `Phantomjs` , `Prerender.io` , and other tools.

**But The question is :**

*Do I get the `100% SEO` using these tools or generating the pages at server side is a better decision?*

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because SEO questions belong on [webmasters.se]

Comment: @Hobo Sapiens:thank you , but I'm asking about a design decision.

Comment: Read the google SEO guidleines. There are lots and lots of articles on ths topic also. Question is opinion based and therefore off topic here

Comment: Close vote from me, too, for the same reason. Please ask on Webmasters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you will not automatically get 100% SEO, because inserting robots meta tags, canonical links etc in the header is not an easy task in Angular.js. You can't implement full blown SEO without those tags. If you pregenerate on the server side, you may have more control on these.